# jQuery Cycle Next and Prev with onBefore callback for animated text content

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a jQuery Cycle slideshow, consisting of images with additional text used as headline style text. The images fade in, with the text (placed in divs) animating in and out, roughly at the same time as the images using the before callback method. I am trying to now add previous and next controls. They work, but they immediately advance to the next/previous slide, because the before callback is on a delay, they don't seem to be triggering the before callback. I am wondering how to get this whole system working, and have the animated text fade in at the same time as the image if I click the previous and next controls.

What is the best way to tackle this setup? Am I on the right path or is there a more efficient and proper way to go about this? Code below, thanks in advance!

```
<div id="sliderCont">
    <a href="#" id="prev1" name="prev1">PREV</a> <a href="#" id="next1" name=
    "next1">NEXT</a>

    <ul id="slider">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="library/images/car_tarp.jpg" /></a>

        <div class="captionHidden">
          <div class="captionInner">
            <h2 id="slide1_headline1">Unveiling a Revolution</h2>

            <h3 id="slide1_headline2">in Automotive Hospitality</h3>

            <h4 id="slide1_headline3">What Makes Us Different</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="library/images/passion.jpg" /></a>

        <div class="captionHidden">
          <div class="captionInner">
            <h2 id="slide2_headline1">Providing the Blueprint For</h2>

            <h3 id="slide2_headline2">Performance with<br />
            Passion</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Next, CSS

```
*, html, body { margin:0;padding: 0; }
#sliderCont {
height: 512px;
width:1200px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#slider {
width: 1200px;
height: 512px;
z-index: 1;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
}
#slider li {
margin: 0;
}
div.caption {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 60px;
z-index: 2;
font-weight: lighter;

}
div.captionHidden {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 60px;
z-index: 2;
width:1080px;
}
div.captionInner {position: relative; width:1080px;}
div.caption span.item {
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #2C2C2C;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0,    0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #E7E7E7;
}
div.caption span.item.second {
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: -5px;
}
span.slider-highlight {
color: #59b5e2;
}

h2#slide1_headline1 { font-size: 79px;text-align: right;font-weight: normal; color:  #353534;}
h3#slide1_headline2 { font-family: "Arial Black", Arial; font-size: 32px;text-align: right;font-weight: bold; color:#353534;}
h4#slide1_headline3 { font-size: 18px;text-align: right;font-weight: normal; color: #353534;}


h2#slide2_headline1 { font-family: "Arial Black", Arial;font-weight: bold; font-size:  32px;text-align:left; color: #ffffff;}
h3#slide2_headline2 { font-size: 79px;text-align: left;font-weight:  normal;color:#ffffff;}
```

Then our jQuery for the cycle:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 800,
        prev: '#prev1',
        next: '#next1',
        easing: 'easeOutCubic',
        timeout: 5000,
        before: onBefore
    });

    function onBefore(curr, next, opts) {
        $(this).children('.captionHidden').css({
            'opacity': '0',
            'top': '0px'
        });
        $(this).children('.captionHidden').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: '60px'
        }, 600, 'easeOutCubic').delay(5000).animate({
            'opacity': 0,
            'top': '-5px'
        }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually went about this another way; I changed the fx to scrollLeft, then put the animation on the after callback (and use the before callback to 'reset' the caption text div containers to opacity:0; and top:0;

```
$(function() {
 $('#slider').cycle({
    fx : 'scrollLeft',
    speed : 700,
    prev:   '#prev1', 
    next:   '#next1',
    easing: 'easeOutCubic',
    timeout: 5000,
    before : onBefore,
    after: onAfter
});

function onBefore(curr,next,opts) {
   $(this).children('.captionHidden').css({'opacity' : '0','top' :'0px'});
 }
function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
   $(this).children('.captionHidden').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: '60px'
   }, 600, 'easeOutCubic')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right then all you really needed to do was just not even using anything for before or after. I wrote a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v3VP2/22/ .

Comment: Thank you Ulan, I was trying however to animate the text contained in the .captionHidden divs, separately from the images - so for example, images slide in from the side, then immediately after the transition finished, the text in caption fades in and slides down from above - so more of an advanced animation slider (clients all want to replicate Flash these days)